# How to customize angular-bootstrap default for typeaheads?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to have better defaults for my application on typeaheads. I am using the latest version of [angular-bootstrap <s>1.2.4</s> 1.3.2](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead).

So far, I have tried to decorate the directive compilation; since contrary to tooltips, `angular-bootstrap` doesn't provide a provider for typeaheads.

```js
module.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibTypeaheadDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;
        directive.compile = function() {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.typeaheadWaitMs = '2000';
                link.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

---

**Edit**:

Here is codepen demonstrating the issue with `typeaheadEditable`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMQwaq?editors=1010.